# How to convert a date given as "20110912T220000"(NSString) to NSDate

Tags: ios, nsdate, ekevent

I am getting start and end dates for my calendar event(while parsing a .ics file) in "20110912T220000" format. How can I convert this to a NSDate to add to add as event(EKEvent)'s startDate property.

If anyone knows please help me soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `NSDateFormatter` for this.

See [Data Formatting Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html) *(the [Date & Time Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html) may also be interesting)*

This is also detailed in [this Technical Note](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html) in Apple's Q&As. **Note that for such situations, you should use the special "en_US_POSIX" locale** as explained in this technical note.

```
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease]];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss"];
NSDate* parsedDate = [df dateFromString:...];
```

Comment: One more doubt, I have been given Time Zone as "US-Eastern". How can I set that using the date formatter. Can I give the same as "[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"US-Eastern"]"

Comment: Thanks for the link to the TN.  BTW, in setLocale, change the '=' to ':'.

Comment: I got the answer for my comment. It is [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"US/Eastern"]; Thank you all. :)

Comment: Yup, you beat me to it for the locale and timezone ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *dateString = @"20110912T220000";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease];  
formatter.locale = locale;
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss";
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"date: %@", date);
```

NSLog() output: `date: 2011-09-13 02:00:00 +0000`

Note, NSLog outputs the data in you local timezone.

Note the single quotes around the 'T' in the date format.

Here is a link to UTS: [date/time format characters](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: Err there's something wrong with your `formatter = @"..."`: you probably forgot the `dateFormat` property here ;)