# NSString to NSDate conversion using NSDateformatter

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a string of date 2010-11-29T00:00:00+05:30 and I want to convert it into `NSDate`.
I want to convert it into 11/29/2010. For this I am doing something like this..

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
textForLabel = @"2010-11-29T00:00:00+05:30";
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString:textForLabel];
NSLog(@"date : %@",myDate);
```

But output is null.

What could be date format for 2010-11-29T00:00:00+05:30 ?

I am not getting what is getting wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

First, get rid of colon in the timezone, as there is no [timezone format identifier](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for '+05:30'

```
textForLabel = [textForLabel
                stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(21,1)
                withString:@""];
```

Then, you will have this string: `2010-11-29T00:00:00+0530`

The following date format can be used:

```
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy:MM:dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz"];
```

Related question: [iPhone NSDateFormatter Timezone Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094730/iphone-nsdateformatter-timezone-conversion)

Comment: There is now the "ZZZZZ" code that will supposedly recognize the timezone with colon.

Answer (score 0):

> textForLabel = 2010-11-29T00:00:00+05:30

That's not a string. I doubt it'll even compile, given the lack of an ending semicolon, but if it does the compiler is probably interpreting it as an expression and assigning the resulting number to `textForLabel`. To make it a string, do this:

```
textForLabel = @"2010-11-29T00:00:00+05:30";
```

Comment: Sorry it was typing mistake but it's string I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
textForLabel = @"2010-11-29T00:00:00+05:30";
NSArray *components = [textForLabel componentsSeperatedByString:@"T"];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString:[components objectAtIndex:0]];
NSLog(@"date : %@",myDate);
```

This is not the desired method, but will work :)

Comment: This will work, with one limitation - timezone shift does not always fall into same date... (+05:30)

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSDate *) getDateFor :(NSString *)ICSDateString
{
    int strLen = [ICSDateString length];    
    NSString * subString1 = [ICSDateString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, strLen - 1)];
    NSLog(@"%d  %d subString1 %@", strLen, subString1.length, subString1);
    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'"];
    [df setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease]];

    NSDate* parsedDate = [df dateFromString:subString1];

    [df release];
    NSLog(@"parsedDate %@", parsedDate);
    return parsedDate;
}
```

Think, this is the correct way to get NSDate from a ICS formatted date. Have a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7554525/1424174) for reference.
 Thanks.